# asp.net MVC3 unobtrusive validation causes IE8 browser to hang

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, unobtrusive-validation

I am using unobtrusive validation to validate a form. It works in most of the browsers - IE7, IE8 in compatibility mode, FF and Chrome. However, in IE8 stand-alone mode, it fires the validation and message is shown. When I go to the field and retype the value there, the browser hangs **after the first key press**. The error message is not automatically disappearing. This happens for all forms and for all types of validation attributes - Required, Remote or Regular expression.

I am using jquery 1.6.4 and jquery validation 1.8.1.

Could anybody please help me ?

**View Model**

```
namespace xxxxx.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// SubjectVM
    /// </summary>
    public class SubjectVM
    {
        #region Public Properties

        #region SubjectID
        /// <summary>
        /// SubjectID
        /// </summary>
        public int SubjectID { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Name
        /// <summary>
        /// Name
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "Subject Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Name of the subject")]
        [Remote("IsSubjectNameUnique", "Subject", AdditionalFields = "SubjectID",
            ErrorMessage = "The Name given for Subject is already used for another Subject. Please give a different Name.")]
        [UIHint("SingleLineText")]
        [HtmlProperties(MaxLength = 50, Size = 30)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Description
        /// <summary>
        /// Description
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [StringLength(500)]
        [UIHint("MultiLineText")]
        [HtmlProperties(Rows = 4, Cols = 25, MaxLength = 500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Code
        /// <summary>
        /// Code
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "Subject Code")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter subject code")]
        [Remote("IsSubjectCodeUnique", "Subject", AdditionalFields = "SubjectID",
            ErrorMessage = "The Subject Code given is already used for another Subject. Please give a different Subject Code.")]
        [HtmlProperties(MaxLength = 10, Size = 30)]
        [UIHint("SingleLineText")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Action**

```
#region Create
/// <summary>
/// Create
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public override ActionResult Create()
{
    SubjectVM blankObject = new SubjectVM();

    return View("Subject", blankObject);
}
#endregion
```

**View**

```
    @model xxxx.SubjectVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Subject";
}

<h2>Subject</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Subject</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**UI Hint - SingleLineText**

```
@model string
@using xxxx.MVCLibrary;

@{
    HtmlPropertiesAttribute htmlAttributes = null;

    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("HtmlAttributes"))
    {
        htmlAttributes = (HtmlPropertiesAttribute)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["HtmlAttributes"];
    }

    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model, htmlAttributes.HtmlAttributes());
}
```

Comment: Can you cut your code down and prove the error in a sample you can paste here to look at?

Comment: I have added the source code. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Madhu - did you have any luck working out how to overcome this issue. I have a similar problem with ie8

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest version of [jquery validation 1.9](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Unfortunately, this does not fix the issue.

Comment: In an another project, the html generated for the Validation message is <span class="" jQuery16209507216645961215="8" htmlFor="Name" generated="true">. But, in this project, the html generated is <span class="" jQuery16209507216645961215="8" for="Name" generated="true">. i.e. "for" instead of "htmlFor". I think, this is the reason. (I have taken this html using developer tools in IE8.) But, how do I correct this ?